# How to visualize CLOB content - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, clob, ora-00997

I want to select and visualize the content of a column with `CLOB` datatype (>100 bytes).

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ds_cirurgia,1,4000))
  from AVISO_CIRURGIA
 where cd_paciente = 123456789;
```

But I get this error:

```
[SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 997, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
```

I used `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR())` in another column and it works.

What is wrong in this case?

Comment: please post the result of select data_type from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'AVISO_CIRURGIA' and column_name = upper('ds_cirurgia');

Comment: For CLOB you can use GetClobVal() function

Comment: Hi @MarmiteBomber. Thanks for you help. I ran the query you suggested but it seems my user_tab_columns is empty. When I execute a simple select, like: "select ds_cirurgia from AVISO_CIRURGIA ", it shows me each line  as "CLOB, size in bytes", for exemplo: "CLOB,202 Bytes" in the first line, "CLOB,482 Bytes" in the second line....

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. Now it works using: select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS  where table_name = 'AVISO_CIRURGIA' and column_name = upper('ds_cirurgia');                                                                            TABLE_NAME: AVISO_CIRURGIA COLUMN_NAME: DS_CIRURGIA DATA_TYPE: LONG

Comment: @Henrique Amaral what you get as a result of this query? Check also the swapped parameter in DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(col_name,**1,4000**)  - should be **4000,1**

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave it with the call to `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`: it returns a `varchar2`:

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(ds_cirurgia,1,4000)
from   AVISO_CIRURGIA
where  cd_paciente = 123456789
```

However, keep in mind that Oracle SQL is only capable of having a `varchar2` with 4000 bytes, not 4000 characters. Your call can fail if the string contains Unicode characters.

Comment: Why on earth do you edit in your own version of the truth. Let OP edit his question if you are right, but I don't thnk you are.

Answer (score 0):

Your column type is **LONG** not CLOB. Simple look up it in USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

[Here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430) are some workaround how to resolve it. I'd recoment to change the type to CLOB with CTAS.

```
create table t1 as
select ...
to_lob(c) c  /* convert to CLOB */
from t;
```

After that you can simple cast to VARCHAR such as

```
 cast (substr(col_name,1,4000) as varchar2(4000))
```

**UPDATE**

of course you may also use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR

```
 DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(col_name,4000,1)
```

but please note the signature of this function: 2nd parameter is length, 3rd offset (not vice versa as in substr).